# Errors when set column in df to extracted pattern given condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Where `col1` contains `<` followed by any number of spaces and any digits, I want to set `col2` to the digits.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['62', '4 < s', '5<77', '< 10 '], 'col2': [3, 4, None, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


col1        col2
0   62      3.0
1   4 < s   4.0
2   5<77    NaN
3   < 10    9.0
```

This code correctly extracts the digit I want after the pattern:

```
df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   77
3   10
```

However, when I try to set `col2` to that line in a `loc` statement, the outcome is unexpected. Where the condition is true, it sets `col2` to null.

```
df.loc[(df['col1'].str.contains(r'<\s*\d+')),
       'col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')

    col1    col2
0   62      3.0
1   4 < s   4.0
2   5<77    NaN
3   < 10    NaN
```

What's more confusing is in my use case, `col2` will be made of strings. When I make this change and run the same code, I get a ValueError:

```
d = {'col1': ['62', '4 < s', '5<77', '< 10 '], 'col2': ['3', '4', None, '9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.loc[(df['col1'].str.contains(r'<\s*\d+')),
       'col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4w/zhsn7cr924bdcsncw_23jrf80000gn/T/ipykernel_88905/3527715470.py in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[(df['col1'].str.contains(r'<\s*\d+')),
      2        'col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')
      3 df

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/envs/venv-slp2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    721 
    722         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 723         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    724 
    725     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/envs/venv-slp2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1730             self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1731         else:
-> 1732             self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
   1733 
   1734     def _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name: str):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/envs/venv-slp2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_single_block(self, indexer, value, name)
   1960 
   1961         elif isinstance(value, ABCDataFrame) and name != "iloc":
-> 1962             value = self._align_frame(indexer, value)
   1963 
   1964         # check for chained assignment

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/envs/venv-slp2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _align_frame(self, indexer, df)
   2199             return val
   2200 
-> 2201         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with DataFrame")
   2202 
   2203 

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

Comment: Your sample code and sample dataframe don't match.

Comment: You don't have `62` in your first sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.str.extract` returns a dataframe, you may need extract the first column from it

```py
df.loc[m, 'col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to keep original column values when `Series.str.extract` does not find a match: use the [`.fillna(df[your_new_col_name])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

You can use

```py
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')[0].fillna(df['col2'])
```

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['62', '4 < s', '5<77', '< 10 '], 'col2': [3, 4, None, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)')[0].fillna(df['col2'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    col1 col2
0     62  3.0
1  4 < s  4.0
2   5<77   77
3  < 10    10
```

**Notes**

- `type(df['col1'].str.extract(r'<\s*(\d+)'))` outputs *`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`*, you need to extract the first column value by using the `[0]` index
- `.fillna(df['col2'])` fills the NA values with the original value from `col2`.